# Looping over Flask-SQLAlchemy filter query gives 'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Comic'

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to loop over a result set from my filter by Query, and based on a couple of if checks update / insert into my database.

```py
        qs = self.name
        like = "%{}%".format(qs)
        checkName = Comic.query.filter(Comic.comicName.like(f'%{qs}%')).all()

        for i in checkName:
         if self.name != checkName[i].comicName:
            comic = Comic(comicName = self.name,comicAuthor = self.author, comicPrice = self.price, comicDescription = self.description,comicStatus = self.status,comicImage = self.image,comicFrontImage = self.frontImage)
            db.session.add(comic)
            db.session.commit()
         elif self.name == checkName[i].comicName:
            Comic.query.filter_by(comicName=self.name).update({Comic.comicName : self.name})
            db.session.commit()
```

The error is being thrown in the `for i in checkName` loop

giving me the `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Comic` error, inspecting the `checkName` variable it seems to be comprised of `Comics` with indexes pointing to the location in the array,

How would I be able to loop over my checkName variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
for item in checkName:
  if self.name != item.comicName:
  ...
```

Comment: Well that was a lot easier than I thought it would be, thank you and sorry for wasting your time with this question